# Nancy and IdentityServer4 on Net Core?

Tags: nancy, identityserver4

Great [docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/index.html) and [samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts) for [IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4). And likewise for [Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy). But running into some issues getting Nancy + IdentityServer4 together. Anyone done this yet? When I add this to the API Startup:

```
        app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "http://localhost:55555",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

            ApiName = "MyAPI"
        });
```

It fails to resolve UrlEncoder when the service starts up. Plus I'm not sure how to configure the authorization requirements in Nancy modules. Any direction appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add Url encoder [here](https://github.com/Sphiecoh/MusicStore/blob/master/src/NancyMusicStore/Startup.cs#L36-L37)
2. Identity [setup](https://github.com/Sphiecoh/MusicStore/blob/master/src/NancyMusicStore/Startup.cs#L53-L63)
3. Module [setup](https://github.com/Sphiecoh/MusicStore/blob/master/src/NancyMusicStore/Modules/CheckOutModule.cs#L33)

Comment: Awesome, thank you Sifiso! I was also missing the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect package which brings in the extensions methods for adding the encoder.

Comment: Oh whoops, forget the last thing I said about needing the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect package. In my testing different things out I forgot I had removed the IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation package which, when I put that back in instead, also brings in the necessary dependencies...